# Laravel: Can't visualize an image on Storage::url()

Tags: php, laravel

First things first, I upload an image to a `Storage::` in the controller like this:

```
$ranker = Ranker::create([ ... ]);

if ($request->file('file')) {
  $filename = Storage::put('ranker', $request->file('file');
  $ranker->image_url = $filename;
  $ranker->save();
}
```

So this is working, in the database I got a url in the proper field, something like: `ranker/v14rzsqJjlJIEYG2Cd22l1MLxeNPd0hGI0rvLjrf.png`. If I go to `\app\Storage\app\ranker` I see the file, and it is correctly uploaded.

Now, when I want to render the file I do something simple as:

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url($ranker->image_url) }}" ... >
```

The src correctly says: `/storage/ranker/v14rzsqJjlJIEYG2Cd22l1MLxeNPd0hGI0rvLjrf.png` but displays nothing. If I go to `http://server/storage/ranker/v14rzsqJjlJIEYG2Cd22l1MLxeNPd0hGI0rvLjrf.png` I got a 404

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Storage folder is not a publicly accessible folder, so you either need to save the image in the public directory or link the storage public folder to the public folder by running the following artisan command in the cli.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then when saving you need to add it to the public folder by choosing the public disk as default or selecting the disk like this

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('ranker', $request->file('file'));
```

And then output:-

```
{{ Storage::disk('public')->url($ranker->image_url) }}
```

Comment: Oh really? I was very used to move the file on my own to the `/public/img/ranker` this was my first try with `Storage::`. I'll check that! I feel dumb, because of course that must be in the docs I didn't read ‍♂️

Comment: Yes its in the docs under File Storage, here is the link https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Answer (score 1):

As said by ColinMD, The Storage folder is not a publicly accessible folder.

In addition to his solution, you could also make a route in routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/images/{filename}', [ImagesController::class, 'show'])->name("images");
```

Make an ImagesController with the function show as follows:

```
public function show($filename) {
  $content = Storage::get("ranker/$filename");
  return response($content)->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
}
```

This way you can keep your files in your private part of te application, and simply call them by url

```
https://server/images/filename
```

Or in the blade file

```
{{ Route('images', ['filename']) }}
```

Comment: That's a pretty clever idea and a great suggestion. I'll try to implement that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would only recommend this if you want to put your images behind a middleware, like auth so only logged in users receive them, there is a performance hit to doing a PHP request to download an image, it also has to do it for each image on the page.  It wont make a huge difference for a few images, I have one site that can download around 1000 images in a request and it made a massive difference to performance, cant remember the exact amount but I'm sure it was around 10 x quicker to not hit PHP. Allowing the browser to just pick the image from a public folder is going to be far more performant